# How keep a UWP AppWindow fullscreen when another AppWindow enters Fullscreen on 2nd monitor?

Tags: windows, uwp

I'm trying to open 2 AppWindows (*appWindowOne* & *appWindowTwo*) on separate monitors in full screen but when *appWindowTwo* opens *appWindowOne* minimizes. I've tried making the AppWindow re-enter full screen programmatically but it causes the other AppWindow to minimize. When manually clicked in the taskbar it restores to full screen without affecting the other but I would like to know if it's possible to do it programmatically?

```
public static async void ShowAppWindows()
{
    AppWindow appWindowOne = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
    Frame frameOne = new Frame();
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(appWindowOne, frameOne);

    AppWindow appWindowTwo = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
    Frame frameTwo = new Frame();
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(appWindowTwo, frameTwo);

    FullScreenPresentationConfiguration FSPC = new FullScreenPresentationConfiguration()
    {
         IsExclusive = false
    };

    await appWindowOne.TryShowAsync();
    appWindowOne.RequestMoveToDisplayRegion(displayRegions[0]);
    appWindowOne.Presenter.RequestPresentation(FSPC);

    await appWindowTwo.TryShowAsync();
    appWindowTwo.RequestMoveToDisplayRegion(displayRegions[1]);
    appWindowTwo.Presenter.RequestPresentation(FSPC);
}
```

Comment: Could you tried set a task delay before make appWindowTwo into fullscreen?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, You were right! 200ms delay and both AppWindows are going fullscreen like magic. Thanks for your help, you da man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . I've tried making the AppWindow re-enter full screen programmatically but it causes the other AppWindow to minimize.

This looks UI-thread was broken when make `appWindowTwo` into full screen.  I guess setting two windows in a row in full screen will exhaust the UI thread. So, we could  try to call a `Task.Delay()` before making `appWindowTwo` into full screen.