# How to make UWP AppWindow enter full screen mode?

Tags: c#, uwp, fullscreen, uwp-appwindow

I'm using `AppWindow` to create multiple windows for the app, and I want the user to be able to make the windows full screen, but `ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode` doesn't work, it returns false all the time when used in an `AppWindow`.

[Sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode?view=winrt-19041#examples) from Microsoft Docs:

```
private void ToggleFullScreenModeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    if (view.IsFullScreenMode)
    {
        view.ExitFullScreenMode();
    }
    else
    {
        view.TryEnterFullScreenMode(); // Returns false in an AppWindow
    }
}
```

How do you make an `AppWindow` enter full screen mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `AppWindow` you should use `AppWindowPresenter.RequestPresentation` and pass `AppWindowPresentationKind.FullScreen` as parameter.

The solution I came up with (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603569/how-keep-a-uwp-appwindow-fullscreen-when-another-appwindow-enters-fullscreen-on)) handles exiting full screen mode using:

- The original button.
- The back to window button in the title bar.
- The escape key.

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="ToggleFullScreenButton" Text="Full screen mode" Click="ToggleFullScreenButton_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
public AppWindow AppWindow { get; } // This should be set to the AppWindow instance.

private void ToggleFullScreenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var configuration = AppWindow.Presenter.GetConfiguration();
    if (FullScreenButton.Text == "Exit full screen mode" && _tryExitFullScreen())
    {
        // Nothing, _tryExitFullScreen() worked.
    }
    else if (AppWindow.Presenter.RequestPresentation(AppWindowPresentationKind.FullScreen))
    {
        FullScreenButton.Text = "Exit full screen mode";

        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(500); // Delay a bit as AppWindow.Changed gets fired many times on entering full screen mode.
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                AppWindow.Changed += AppWindow_Changed;
                this.KeyDown += Page_KeyDown;
            });
        });
    }
}

private bool _tryExitFullScreen()
{
    if (AppWindow.Presenter.RequestPresentation(AppWindowPresentationKind.Default))
    {
        FullScreenButton.Text = "Full screen mode";
        AppWindow.Changed -= AppWindow_Changed;
        this.KeyDown -= Page_KeyDown;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// handles the back-to-window button in the title bar
private void AppWindow_Changed(AppWindow sender, AppWindowChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DidSizeChange) // DidSizeChange seems good enough for this
    {
        _tryExitFullScreen();
    }
}

// To make the escape key exit full screen mode.
private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Escape)
    {
        _tryExitFullScreen();
    }
}
```